# A search bar in my web app that returns a list of results from my models in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm creating a web application that will allow people to search book titles, authors, publishers etc. from a database. The database is loaded and ready to go to Django, but I'm struggling to find out how to proceed.

I assume I need to create a webpage with a form that accepts keywords that the user wants to search for, but how do I then search the database (which Django file would this code go into?) for the keyword and output the result in a list?

Sorry if this is super broad. If this is a common question, I can delete it. I would appreciate any help and/or links that could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Work through the Django documentation. It is very useful and should be able to solve this problem. Start with their tutorial and learn how the Model/View/Template style works.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/

Once you understand this, searching by title is very easy via a queryset. You'd use something like this (which would go in your "views.py" file):

```
     Book.objects.filter(title__contains="SearchTerm")
```

More about that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/search/